# Подписка на уведомления по почте

Tags: поддержка, faq

С переходом на новую платформу многие пользователи начали испытывать проблемы с подписками на вопросы, так как система подписок на Stack Exchange сильно отличается от используемой ранее.

Каким же образом работает система нотификации на новом сайте?

Answer (score 1):

Все нотификации на сайте и, более, всей Сети поступают в ваш [глобальный ящик уведомлений](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/).

Для активации уведомлений, отправляемых по электронной почте, перейдите на страницу вашей [учётной записи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current). Для этого необходимо нажать на ваше имя пользователя в верхней панели сайта.

[image: Профиль пользователя]

Затем выберете секцию "Править", далее перейдите в раздел "Параметры".

[image: Секция править]

Вам необходимо указать адрес электронной почты, на которую вы бы хотели получать уведомления, а затем подтвердить его.

[image: Адрес электронной почты]

Далее выберите, как часто вы хотите получать письма: `каждые 3 часа`, `ежедневно` или `еженедельно`.

[image: Настройка частоты получения уведомлений]

Пожалуйста, помните, что в письме вам будут отправляться только те нотификации, которые вы не просмотрели через ваш глобальный почтовый ящик на сайте! Например, если вы решили использовать "ежедневную" подписку и при этом вы не просматривали входящие уведомления через какой-либо сайт сети Stack Exchange в течение 24 часов, то вы получите уведомление, которое будет содержать все нотификации за этот период. Вы также можете выбрать более "настойчивую" подписку - "каждые 3 часа", которая, на мой взгляд, наибольшим образом похожа на "старую" систему уведомлений.

Данный подход преследует оду цель - простоту. Если какая-либо нотификация (например, об ответе на ваш вопрос, комментарии к вашему сообщению, обращение к @вам в комментариях, обращение к @вам в чате и так далее) с любого сайта сети Stack Exchange поступит в ваш глобальный ящик, вы получите уведомление об этом по почте. Все это означает, что более не надо беспокоится о подписках на почтовые уведомления на каждом отдельном сайте Сети, все обрабатывается автоматически.

К слову, вы также [можете подписаться](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters) на новостную рассылку любого сайта сети Stack Exchange!

---

Это свободный перевод статьи “[Improved Global Email Notifications](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/improved-global-email-notifications/)”.

Comment: Резюме: нормальной подписки нет и не будет :(

Comment: Тут два момента. 1) Возможно я просто не рассказал про "нормальную" подписку. Чтобы понять, что я про нее не рассказал или выяснить, какая подписка "нормальная",  2) пожалуйста, опишите в отдельном вопросе, что именно следует добавить, чтобы подписка стала "отличной".

Comment: Да уже вроде обсуждали. Нормальная подписка - это немедленное получение на почту всех событий, на которые подписался.  Например, "новый ответ к вопросу 123", "комментарий к ответу на вопрос 456", "новая редакция вопроса 789", etc. Само собой, с содержанием ответа/коммента/новой редакции. В общем, полной и полезной информации, а не "что-то произошло, подробности по ссылке". Только, боюсь, упрётся это всё не в возможности движка, а в почтовый трафик SO :) Но в любом случае, текущая система для меня, например, совершенно бесполезна.

Comment: Вива ля @klopp!
Я об этом поведении сразу после переезда начал спрашивать. И тогдашние боссы сказали что такого нет и не предвидится.

Comment: Nicolas Chabanovsky, верно ли понял, что если я подписался на уведомления по почте на <http://ru.stackoverflow.com> как в Вашем руководстве, то буду получать уведомления об ответах, комментариях и т. д. со всех проектов Stack Exchange? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Вы будете получать рассылку только того сайта, на котором подписываетесь. Подписаться на остальные сайты вы можете на [странице подписок](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters). ваши текущие подписки вы можете найти в [профиле сети](http://stackexchange.com/users/7696365/?tab=subscriptions).